# Values of the Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry

Are the values of the christoffel symbols the same for all coordinate systems on a surface/manifold? I would love to see an example for the cone in two different parametrizations.

Comment: Around every point you can choose [normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates) in which the christoffel symbols vanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. The reason is that the Christoffel symbols are not scalar fields, nor tensor fields, they might vanish completely in a coordinate system and yet be non-vanishing in another.

As a simple example consider the plane in cartesian coordinates: All Christoffel symbols vanish. Now consider polar coordinates, there will be some which are non-vanishing.